# Is it possible to use the free Wi-Fi at the Zurich Airport when one cannot receive a text message?

Tags: internet, wifi, zurich

Is it possible to use the free Wi-Fi at the Zurich Airport when one cannot receive a text message?

[image]

Comment: I have always found that type system idiotic (receive your password by email or by text when you are traveling far afield without connectivity).  I have gotten around that at other airports by asking at the service desks and getting them to generate a short time password with their phones.